# Rabbit MQ Filtering

Tags: rabbitmq

We have a RabbitMQ exchange that is exchanging messages between several components of our system.

Each component is both a publisher and subscriber of the exchange.

We need to find a way of ensuring that each application does not receive messages it sends into the exchange.

For example.

App 1 sends a refresh message. We want this to go to all subscribers of the exchange apart from App 1

I can see that you can specify routing attributes, but this seems to define the messages you WANT not the ones you DO NOT WANT.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're asking for is not directly possible with RabbitMQ. It's a bit backward from how RMQ works, and how the system should be designed.

That is, you can't filter or be "selective" about which messages a given consumer receives. Ultimately, [the "selective consumer" is an anti-pattern in RabbitMQ](http://derickbailey.com/2015/07/22/airport-baggage-claims-selective-consumers-and-rabbitmq-anti-patterns/). Once a message is in a queue, a consumer listening to that queue may receive that message (depending on how many consumers are attached, etc).

The best way to handle this, in my experience, is to either change your RMQ topology and application design so that this won't be a problem (may not be possible) or to have your app know which message it sent, and ignore anything it sent.

I think the first option is better (ensure this isn't going to happen with good app / topology design), but the second option is often easier...

To do this, you can add a custom property to your message, like "publisher-id" or similar. Have your consumer code check to make sure the publisher-id of the message does *not* match it's own publisher-id. If it does match, ack the message without doing anymore. If it does not match, process the message normally.

Comment: did think this would be the case, but just wanted to check there was not something within RMQ that did it first. Redesign is not an option, as this message is a cache-reset message that indicates that the database has been updated and all nodes should drop their local cache of that type. as such has to both subscribe and listen

Comment: Is it possible to include to back message from consumer some data? And store that in queue or get on server and store in db?

Comment: What about the case of reducing mirrored traffic to a testing consumer? We've used one upstream exchange to publish to both a testing and production environment but would like to reduce costs and filter out a portion of the stream from within RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign individual routing keys for each component (e.g. `app1`, `app2`, `app3`, ...) and subscribe each component to all other routing keys excepts its own.

So when App 1 sends a message it will send it with routing key `app1` but it is subscribed only to `app2`, `app3`, ....

Comment: agree this would work, but our app will potentially have hundreds of nodes so statically defining them is not an option.

Comment: Then you should probably go with the solution proposed by @Derick Bailey. At least, I don't know any other options.